# How can i wrap a string with dollar sign?

Tags: javascript, string

I am looking ways to wrap a string for example i want convert string `"student"` to  `"$student$"`. How can i achieve that in javascript?

Comment: You can use the `+` operator to concatenate 2 strings

Comment: @mousetail can you give an example please,sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of template literals like that:

```js
const wrapIntoDollars = (string) => {
  return `$${string}$`;
}

console.log(wrapIntoDollars("student"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,sir. I appricated. @sm3sher